# Mysql recursive query in

Tags: mysql, sql, select, entity-attribute-value

friends. Mysql DB has 4 tables
products, product_properties, properties, property_values

**products**

```
|Id|name|
|1 |Book1|
|2 |Book2|
|3 |Book3|
```

...

**properties**

```
|Id|name|
|1 |Color|
|2 |Binding|
```

...

**property_values**

```
|Id|property_id|value  |
|1 |1          | red   |
|2 |1          | orange|
|3 |1          | green |
|4 |2          | soft  |
|5 |2          | hard  |
```

**product_properties**

```
|Id|product_id|property_id| value |
|1 |1         |1          | 1
|2 |1         |2          | 4
|3 |2         |1          | 1
|4 |2         |2          | 4
|5 |3         |1          | 2
```

I need to get a list of products that have color red and binding soft. But I'm confused.

```
select products.id from products 
join product_properties on product_properties.product_id = products.id 
join properties on properties.id = product_properties.property_id
join property_values on property_values.id = product_properties.value
where properties.name = 'Color' and property_values.value = 'red'
and properties.name = 'Binding' and property_values.value = 'soft'
```

...not working...

Comment: any error? some logs?

Comment: Please post SQL script

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1):

You are very close:

```
select pp.id
from product_properties pp join
     properties p
     on p.id = pp.property_id join
     property_values pv
     on pv.id = pp.value
where (p.name = 'Color' and pv.value = 'red') or
      (p.name = 'Binding' and pv.value = 'soft')
group by pp.id
having count(distinct p.name) = 2;
```

Note:  I removed the `products` table, because it is not needed for the query.

This selects the properties that meet your conditions.  It then selects the products that have two matches.

Answer (score -1):

I would write the joins as INNER JOIN. I work most times with that and works fine.

```
SELECT p.id
FROM products p
INNER JOIN product_properties r ON (p.id = r.property_id)
WHERE r.value ='red'
```

its not your complete query but i hope i will understand :-)

more information: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

Answer (score -1):

Your statement is good... check [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/73d7d/1/0)

Answer (score -1):

Try this, man.

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    products
WHERE
    Id IN (
            SELECT 
                DISTINCT(pdc.id) AS product_id 
            FROM 
                products pdc
                INNER JOIN product_properties pp ON (pp.product_id = pdc.Id)
                INNER JOIN properties prop ON (prop.Id = pp.property_id)
                INNER JOIN property_values ppv ON (ppv.Id = pp.value)
            WHERE
                pp.value = 1 
        ) AND
    Id IN (
            SELECT 
                DISTINCT(pdc.id) AS product_id 
            FROM 
                products pdc
                INNER JOIN product_properties pp ON (pp.product_id = pdc.Id)
                INNER JOIN properties prop ON (prop.Id = pp.property_id)
                INNER JOIN property_values ppv ON (ppv.Id = pp.value)
            WHERE
                pp.value = 4 
        )
```

ps. Under that modeling you'll not need the property_id column on the table  product_properties.

Comment: DISTINCT is not a function.

Comment: Yeap, I know it. Any problem with the query?

Comment: Yes. pp.value can never be both 1 and 4 simultaneously.

Comment: The OP is interested in situations that are both red AND soft.

Comment: I changed the query, think it's not the ideal solution, but it'll gonna work.

Comment: I doubt it - although I'd be happy to be proven wrong. But either way, it seems like a satisfactory answer has already been provided.

Comment: Sounds like a plan ;-)